# Detecting window focus the angular way?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a good angular way to detect window focus?  I am using html5 notifications and I would like to only fire if the window is out of focus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a built-in angular directive `ngFocus` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) maybe it helps if you attach it to the body

```
<window, input, select, textarea, a
  ng-focus="">
...
</window, input, select, textarea, a>
```

Edit: For window focus, there's the `$window` wrapper and you can do something like:

```
 $window.onfocus = function(){
   console.log("focused");
 }
```

Comment: How do you attach it to the body element?  Do you have a separate controller owning the body tag?

Comment: Hm I guess it depends on how your layout is structured now. I have the `ngApp` attached to `<html>` and `ngController` attached to `<body>`. Can you try and do that? You can add `ngFocus` on the `<body>`, also. If not, I guess you can attach it to some sort of wrapper/main content `<div>` that covers the whole surface. I also added a `ng-controller="RootCtrl"` to the `index.html` file for occasions like these. TL;DR **yes**

Comment: Hmm, my ng-controller="layoutController" is on a div directly inside my body tag, but i added ng-focus="focus()" and a $scope.focus method inside my layout controller and no luck.  i also tried moving the layoutController and the ng-focus directive to the body tag and no luck... maybe im doing something wrong?

Comment: maybe you need something like blur instead of focus then? What version of angular are you using?

Comment: had blur and focus on the element:  ng-focus="focus()"
  ng-blur="blur() -- using 1.3.7 -- to be clear, your solution works for you when you open a different browser tab and click back? and also enter a different application and return to your browser?

Comment: I tried adding a root controller on body and also no luck.

Comment: I think the simplest way to do it would be  `$window.onfocus = function(){
   console.log("focused");
 }` let me know if it works. Don't forget to dependency inject `$window` in your controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68248/discussion-between-cristi-berceanu-and-fotoflo).

Answer (score 5):

**Edit** @CristiBerceanu is right - you should use the built-in ng-focus directive. However, take this answer as a guideline for any missing event you want to bind.

You must create a directive:

```
angular
  .module('MyModule', [])
  .directive('onFocus', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'focus': '&onFocus'
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            var focus = function(event) {
                $scope.focus({'$event': event});
            };
            $element.on("focus", focus);
            $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
                $element.off('focus', onClick);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Notice how the event is bound in the directive by jquery and NOT directly in the controller. Additionally, notice that a bound expression is tied using the `&` prefix (evaluable expression binding) instead of regular prefixes like `@` (text-binding) or `=` (scope property reference, bi-directional, binding).

Answer (score 4):

In Cristi Berceanu's answer, he suggests assigning a function to $window.onfocus, which does work.  However, there is a problem with that... only one function can be assigned to $window.focus at a time. Thus, by assigning a function to $window.onfocus, you could accidentally overwrite a previous function, and your function will be vulnerable to being overwritten later, too.

Here's a different solution that allows multiple functions to run with the window's focus or blur events:

```
var onFocus = function () {
    // do something
};

var onBlur = function () {
    // do something else
};

var win = angular.element($window);

win.on("focus", onFocus);
win.on("blur", onBlur);
```

This will allow you to assign multiple functions to the focus and blur events for the $window object.

If you added the functions inside a controller and want to remove those functions when the controller is destroyed, you can do something like this:

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function handler() {
    win.off("focus", onFocus);
    win.off("blur", onBlur);
    $interval.cancel(interval);
});
```

Solution inspired by this post: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2934-handling-window-blur-and-focus-events-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 1):

you can write a directive to attach to the body element  and inside it you can use $window.onfocus event to notify your angular app using events or a service, the same thing you can do from inside a service, it all depends on your architecture