# ng-focus does not work with iframe in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, focus, listener

ng-focus does not work with iframe in AngularJS. What may I be missing here?

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<iframe src="example.com" tabindex="-1" ng-focus="alert('foo');">

</iframe>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pnfw4mr5/2/)

Is it even supposed to work or will focus work with all elements but the iframe?

Comment: not really a react problem, I do not think Iframe has a focus event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngFocus is supported for the elements window, input, select, textarea and a as the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) say. Setting ngFocus for an iframe won't work.

As the example in the docs say, those are the supported elements for ngFocus.

```js
<window, input, select, textarea, a
  ng-focus="expression">
...
</window, input, select, textarea, a>
```

Also check this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angularjs-ng-focus-directive/), there it's pretty clear.

For the window object focus you can use the `$window` wrapper in the following way:

```js
$window.onfocus = function(){
   console.log("focused");
 }
```

Comment: Also I am curious how is it possible to add the ng-focus to a window. Could you, please, add an example?

Comment: I guess you would have to do it programmatically: `$window.setAttribute('ng-focus', 'foo');`. Hope it helps :)

Comment: But AngularJS is against any DOM modifications which are out of a directive`s context. And since I am anaware (maybe you are) of any way to add a directive to a window I think that there should be other way

Comment: I've just edited my answer with what I think is the right way to do it. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: For more information I think this article could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789326/detecting-window-focus-the-angular-way

Comment: Does it mean that we can get an iframe`s window somehow and set the ng-focus for it? That would tehcnichally mean the same as setting the ng-focus for an iframe.